# Windows shows me the thumbnail images but doesn't create Thumbs.db

Tags: thumbs.db

I have some `Revit` files in a folder which Windows Explorer shows me the their thumbnails. See below.

[image: Sceenshot]

However, I cannot locate `thumbs.db` in the folder. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your folder options and make sure you have the circled items on this image selected as they are in the image.

[image: Folder Options]

If you do and it still isn't creating a Thumbs.db file then that is because these files aren't supported by windows natively. They just have an image preview handler and the preview images are being handled by an explorer extension (which would never use the MS Thumbs.db file). If it is an extension and it is caching the previews it isn't saving the cached info in Thumbs.db.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My case is what you described in the last paragraph of your answer. Any idea how I can get access to those thumbnail images? I have thousands of these Revit files and I need to have a copy of their thumbnail images. I was hoping that I could muck around with thumbs.db :(

Comment: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/06/rvt-and-rfa-thumbnail-image.html

Comment: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/open-revit-ole-storage.html

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Any explanation about above links is highly appreciated.